# Tkinter GUI is skipped if function is called

Tags: python, user-interface, csv, tkinter

I've written this code in an attempt to add a `GUI` and browse button to my program `CSVModify`.

The problem is if I type `CSVModify()` under my `browseCSV` function, it says `CSVModify` is not defined. If I have `CSVModify` run not indented under `browseCSV` as in the code below, my `GUI` doesn't show up and it skips directly to the `CSVModify` function.

I want the `browseCSV` to run first so I can choose a file, and then I want `CSVModify` to run after that to modify the file I chose, which is stored under the variable filename. I am new to `Python` and coding in general so please help me understand where I went wrong.

```
#attempt to make CSVModifier with GUI
from Tkinter import *
import csv
class Window:
    def __init__(self, master):
        #File Selection
        csvfile=Label(root, text="File").grid(row=1, column=0)
        bar=Entry(master).grid(row=1, column=1)

        #Buttons
        y=7
        self.button1 = Button(root, text="OK", command=master.destroy)
        y+=1
        self.button1.grid(row=10, column=3, sticky = W + E)
        self.button2 = Button(root, text="Browse", command=self.browseCSV)
        self.button2.grid(row=1, column=3)


    def CSVModify(): 
        new_columns = []    
        userinput = raw_input("What string would you like to remove? ") 

        changes = { 
            userinput : '',
            }

        with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for column in reader:
                new_column = column
            for key, value in changes.items():
            new_column = [x.replace(key, value) for x in new_column]
            new_columns.append(new_column)

        with open(("modified" + filename), 'wb') as f: 
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerows(new_columns)


    def browseCSV(self):
        from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
        filename = askopenfilename()
        self.button3 = Button(root, text=filename,)
        self.button3.grid()

    CSVModify()

root = Tk()
window=Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The code I have for `button3` was just for me to test if the file path was being properly found and stored.

Comment: can you first fix your indentation?...may be this is all about your problem?

Comment: Remove `Tk.withdraw`.  That's hiding the GUI.

Comment: I removed Tk.withdraw but the GUI still doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

At least one problem in your code is that you are creating two root windows (`root = Tk()` and `Tk().withdraw()`). Tkinter is designed to have exactly one root window running.

You probably have other problems, but the indentation in the code makes it impossible to know what your code actually looks like.

Comment: Thanks. I've since removed Tk.withdraw and I am working on the indenting right now, please check back for the edit.

Comment: I have just fixed the indentation. Please let me know if there are still any errors in indentation, I'm new to stack overflow and got a bit confused by the code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. Thanks to everyone who commented with helpful solutions and the like. It ended up being the fact that I was defining and calling the CSVModify function completely wrongly. Here is the updated code to anyone that is interested.

```
#attempt to make CSVModifier with GUI
from Tkinter import *
import csv

class Window:
    def __init__(self, master):
        #File Selection
        csvfile=Label(root, text="File").grid(row=1, column=0)
        bar=Entry(master).grid(row=1, column=1)

        #Buttons
        y=7
        self.button1 = Button(root, text="OK", command=master.destroy)
        y+=1
        self.button1.grid(row=10, column=3, sticky = W + E)
        self.button2 = Button(root, text="Browse", command=self.browseCSV)
        self.button2.grid(row=1, column=3)


    def browseCSV(self):
        from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
        filename = askopenfilename()
        self.button3 = Button(root, text=filename)
        self.button3.grid()

def CSVModify(): 
        new_columns = []    
        userinput = raw_input("What string would you like to remove? ") 

        changes = { 
            userinput : '',
            }

        with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for column in reader:
                new_column = column
            for key, value in changes.items():
                new_column = [x.replace(key, value) for x in new_column]
                new_columns.append(new_column)

        with open(("modified" + filename), 'wb') as f: 
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerows(new_columns)


root = Tk()
window=Window(root)
root.mainloop()
CSVModify()
```